# Is there a way to force XCode to provide autocompletion of imports and/or classes in header files that are not included by an implementation file?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, objective-c-protocol

I've noticed that while editing header files, XCode does not auto-suggest header files to import or classes from imported files unless the file you are editing is itself imported by some file that is included in the target.

I kind of get the reasons for this, but it's super lame. I'm very happy to take the trade off of disappointment at compile time (oops! that wasn't a class that I could import) for the benefit of saving a ton of time while writing headers.

By the way I'm aware that I can use forward class and protocol declarations but this is not helpful because I often need to use something whose name I've not committed to memory. Once I know the thing to forward-declare, then I will!

Is there any way to get XCode to be more liberal about this?

Edit: with pictures

Here's what I see in a header file included by an implementation file that is added to a target when I type the letters "#i":

[image: before]

Now I comment out the include of the header I was editing

[image: comment]

Now here's what I get - but autocomplete still works

[image: after]

When I make a new protocol, of course it is not imported by some implementation file (because it is new and it is not a class, so there is no associated implementation file already created).

[image: new protocol]

So autocomplete of imports (and classes) doesn't work... until I import it from an implementation

[image: import protocol]

And now autocomplete works

[image: yay]

Comment: Once you start typing a header name Xcode will usually offer a completion. Otherwise I'm not sure what you're asking for.

Comment: It does not do that for me when I type the header name from a protocol declaration header file and it's not a new thing... it's never done that for me even back in Xcode 3

Comment: That's why I said usually. It's either slow or buggy or both, so you won't always get a completion offered.

Comment: I'm not saying that for you it never works, I'm saying for me I can say it has *never* worked until the header file in question is imported (it behaves deterministically for me)... I've edited my question to clarify